# ng-change is not triggering the function

Tags: angularjs

Unable to trigger the function using ng-change. If I select a same option as before initialization even after initializing it to default value through code.
I want ng-change to call my function even the option selected is same after the initialization

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: What have you done so far add your code

Comment: Can you tell us what the use-case is here? You're basically asking to call a function when nothing changes...

Comment: Actually i had 3 dropdowns which on selection calls one angular function as the first option changed keeping second same is not triggering the function as the first is changed based and second is not changed . But i want the function to trigger as the dropdown one is changed eventhough the second is not changed

Answer (score 0):

ng-change won't work for same option selection. Use ng-click in your case.

Comment: ng-click on the <select> will fire on mousedown... you'll not be able to get the selected value that way.
An ng-click on individual <option> elements won't rigger the function either.

Answer (score 0):

```
//try angular watch
var selectionWatch = $scope.$watch('yourModelValue', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    //your fn
});

//Destroy watch
$scope.$on('$destroy', selectionWatch);
```

Comment: $watch will only trigger if the value being watched is changed. In this case, that does not change, so the $watch will not be triggered.

Comment: so what exactly you want to achieve ? explain it briefly or provide a plunker or jsfiddle..so we can tackle it easily